# Check if counter exists

Tags: counters

I've written a package that introduces a new environment:

```
\newfloat{foo}{htb}{bar}[chapter]
```

The package however can be used for articles, books, ... Since not all of these environments have the concept of `chapter`, on gets a `No counter 'chapter' defined.` exception.

How can I check if the chapter counter is defined?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If a counter `foo` exists then a count `\c@foo` exists as well as a macro `\thefoo`. The `\newcounter` command (that most likely is used by `\newfloat`) actually checks if `\c@foo` exists and calls `\@nocounterr{foo}` if it doesn't.

The following also checks for `\c@foo` using etex's `\ifcsname ...\endcsname`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ifcounter[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Counter \texttt{chapter} \ifcounter{chapter}{exists}{doesn't exist}.

Counter \texttt{section} \ifcounter{section}{exists}{doesn't exist}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\newcommand\ifcounter[3]{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{#3}{#2}}`

Comment: @egreg I know :) I just like `\ifcsname` a tiny bit better since it doesn't leave the command as `\relax` if it isn't defined

Comment: @egreg completely agree with clemens, see a good explanation of this issue [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-isdef.html).

Comment: Why are the `\expandafter`s needed? I figured that the conditional would expand to `\@firstoftwo` (or `\@secondoftwo`), and we'd be left with `\@firstoftwo{exists}{doesn't exist}`.

Comment: @Beelzebielsk see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107753/why-the-expandafter-firstoftwo-idiom

Comment: @cgnieder Seems LaTeX was fixed and newer versions don't leave the command as `\relax` anymore (http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-isdef).

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\ifdef{\thechapter}{\newfloat{foo}{htb}{bar}[chapter]}{}
\begin{document}%
x
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A TeX version of the conditional.
Clemens used the e-TeX `\ifcsname` conditional. I just translated it into the TeX `\ifx`.
I got inspired in [this answer](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=16116).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

 Counter \texttt{chapter} 
 \makeatletter   
 \ifx\c@chapter\undefined
    doesn't exist
 \else
    it exists
 \fi
\makeatother

 Counter \texttt{section}   
 \makeatletter  
 \ifx\c@section\undefined
    doesn't exist
 \else
    exists
 \fi
 \makeatother

 \end{document}
```

The output is exactly the same as the first answer.
May be somebody can tell the advantages/disadvantages compared with the others.

Comment: The `\ifcsname` approach doesn't rely on `\undefined` to really be undefined.

Comment: Is this a shortcoming to rely on `\undefined`?

Comment: Not really, but one should be trustful of package writers, but especially of users, who are fond of giving strange names to their macros. Thus `\@undefined` seems a better choice.